# Hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

Нужно достать из бд все продукты, с определённым типом продавца. Связаны таблицы "многие к одному". Такой вариант не срабатывает (could not extract ResultSet).
Почему?

```
Session session = null;
    String typeF = "Фруктовая";
    try {
        session = HibbUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from ProductEntity where idPoint.type = " + typeF);
        List<ProductEntity> setFrut = query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println(setFrut.size());
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Лог :

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Ð¤Ñ€ÑƒÐºÑ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ�' in 'where clause'
```

Кодировку проверил, вроде всё хорошо.

Классы

```
public class ProductEntity {
    private int id;
    private PointsEntity idPoint;
    private String product;
}//get&set


public class PointsEntity {
    private int idPoint;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private BigDecimal procZp;
    private Set<ProductEntity> products;
}
```

product.xml

```
<many-to-one name="idPoint" class="market.model.modelV2.PointsEntity" fetch="select">
        <column name="id_point" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

point.xml

```
<set name="products" table="product"
         inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="id_point" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="market.model.modelV2.ProductEntity" />
    </set>
```

SQL

```
Hibernate: select productent0_.id as id1_2_, productent0_.id_point as id_point2_2_, productent0_.product as product3_2_, productent0_.price as price4_2_, productent0_.brutto as brutto5_2_, productent0_.summ as summ6_2_, productent0_.b1 as b7_2_, productent0_.b2 as b8_2_, productent0_.b3 as b9_2_, productent0_.b4 as b10_2_, productent0_.b5 as b11_2_, productent0_.b6 as b12_2_, productent0_.b7 as b13_2_, productent0_.b8 as b14_2_, productent0_.b9 as b15_2_, productent0_.b10 as b16_2_, productent0_.b11 as b17_2_, productent0_.rest_y as rest_y18_2_, productent0_.rest_t as rest_t19_2_, productent0_.virKG as virKG20_2_, productent0_.virRUB as virRUB21_2_, productent0_.kassa as kassa22_2_, productent0_.procZP as procZP23_2_, productent0_.date as date24_2_, productent0_.frut as frut25_2_ from market.product productent0_ cross join market.points pointsenti1_ where productent0_.id_point=pointsenti1_.id_point and pointsenti1_.type=Фруктовая
```

Это вообще нормально?

Comment: А в логах что-то есть? Hiberhate хоть запрос посылает? Если да, то попробуйте его руками выполнить, возможно там будет что-то понятно.

Comment: @Vartlok такой запрос вообще должен срабатывать? я просто не очень силён в написании такого

Comment: В логах пишет об неизвестной колонке

Comment: 1. Добавьте эту ошибку в вопрос. 2. Добавьте ваши классы(можно не целиком, главное чтобы маппинг был ясен).

Comment: Окей, судя по всему, запрос пытается выполнится, но что-то идёт не так. Включите отображение SQL, это делается параметром `hibernate.show_sql` в настройках. И в логах перед эксепшеном будет SQL запрос, попробуйте его напрямую выполнить. Похоже у вас какие-то проблемы с именем колонки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас проблема не с именем колонки, а с параметром который вы передаете. [В документации](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-where) первый пример очень похож на ваш и там используются кавычки. Т.е. вам надо поменять запрос на такой:

```
session.createQuery("from ProductEntity where idPoint.type = '" + typeF + "'");
```

Comment: Спасибо, раньше подобные запросы работали и без ковычек

Comment: Ковычки нужны для строковый переменных. А для чисел нужно без кавычек, иначе оно тоже не будет работать.